# Can you input a SQL statement into a freshly created Firebird Database using just the embedded server DLLs?

Tags: firebird

We have a demo application that has an Firebird Database distributed with it in the install package. We use the Firebird Embedded Server DLL files to distibute with it.

We would like to distibute just a plain database with no tables, indexes, etc created in it, since the database is always being updated, we would rather distibute a SQL script that the installer can then run to update the database.

Is it possible to do this with embedded firebase server?  I have always had to have the non-embedded server (Superclassic & Superserver) on my machine to create the database and run the SQL sqript using ISQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISQL is a command line tool that enables the execution of SQL statements either interactively or by input script file. If I Copy isql.exe into the Firebird embedded directory. I can  then use the ISQL command line tool as follows

isql.exe -q -i mydatabase.sql